# Drawing Multiple Graphs Bolded Point

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw multiple functions on one chart and put a bold point at their intersection? I'd like to add an x^3 in the chart created below and put a bold point at (1,1).

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\shade[top color=red,bottom color=gray!50] (0,0) parabola (1.5,2.25) |- (0,0);
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3.9,3.9) [step=0.25cm];
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,4) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {1/1, 1.5/1\frac{1}{2}, 2/2, 3/3}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\xtext$};
    \foreach \y/\ytext in {1/1, 2/2, 2.25/2\frac{1}{4}, 3/3}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};    
    \draw (-.5,.25) parabola bend (0,0) (2,4) node[below right] {$x^2$};

    \draw (-.5,.25) parabola bend (0,0) (2,4) node[below right] {$x^3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused since you are loading the pgfplots package but draw the picture in "plain" Ti*k*Z. I thus base my answer on plain Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\shade[top color=red,bottom color=gray!50] (0,0) parabola (1.5,2.25) |- (0,0);
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3.9,3.9) [step=0.25cm];
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,4) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {1/1, 1.5/1\frac{1}{2}, 2/2, 3/3}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\xtext$};
    \foreach \y/\ytext in {1/1, 2/2, 2.25/2\frac{1}{4}, 3/3}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {$\ytext$};    
    \draw[name path=parabola] (-.5,.25) parabola bend (0,0) (2,4) node[below right] {$x^2$};

    \draw[name path=cubic] plot[variable=\x,domain=-0.5:1.6] ({\x},{\x^3}) node[below right] {$x^3$};
    \fill[blue]  [name intersections={of={parabola} and {cubic}}]
    (intersection-1) circle (2pt);   

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, it finds only one intersection here, but that's the one you were mentioning.

[image]